# Handling environmental variables in package.json

Tags: npm, package.json

Hello Stack Community,

I'd love to achieve something as simple as:

```
    "loadKey": "export GITLAB_KEY=123 || set GITLAB_KEY=123",
    "echoKey": "echo ${GITLAB-KEY}",
```

To make it both cross-operating system compatible and with minimal additional package installations. I see, this topic has been already processed multiple times, with multiped updates, so maybe it's time to get some ultimate solution?

As close as I was able to get, is:

```
    "loadKey": "cross-env GITLAB_KEY=22 npm run pp4",
    "echoKey": "cross-env-shell \"echo $TEST\""
```

#### The questoins:

1. Is it possible to get this behavior *without* any external npm dev dependencies?
2. Why `&&` is so destructive in this construct? This will work:

```
    "load": "cross-env GITLAB_KEY=22",
    "echo": "cross-env-shell \"echo $GITLAB_KEY\"",
    "loadAndEcho": "npm run load npm run echo"
```

but this won't:

```
    "load": "cross-env GITLAB_KEY=22",
    "echo": "cross-env-shell \"echo $GITLAB_KEY\"",
    "loadAndEcho": "npm run load && npm run echo"
```

I've noticed, that with `&&` echo scritp will access globally set evn variable, like directly from BASH `set GITLAB_KEY=GLOBAL`, I'd love to understand the reason and the difference.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with environment variables and compatibility between operating systems in a Node.js environment, it is important to consider the differences in how commands are executed on different platforms. The "cross-env" package is often used to set environment variables in a cross-platform way.

As for the behavior with "&&", its significance in this context lies in the sequence of commands executed. When using "npm run load && npm run echo", the echo command is executed in a separate shell that may not have access to the environment variable set in the previous command. This behavior is due to the nature of how && works in the context of npm run scripts.

```
"loadAndEcho": "node -e \"console.log(process.env.GITLAB_KEY)\""
```

This way directly accesses the environment variable using Node.js without relying on external npm dev dependencies. It provides a platform-independent way to access a set of environment variables using "cross-env" or any other method.